# How to run bundled code before first paint in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I get next.js to build a page such that a given module's code executes immediately, before React has initialized and so on? The purpose of the code is to check localStorage and then optionally apply a dark-mode theme, before the page first paints.

With plain webpack or vite I'd make an entry point for the code I need, and configure things such that that the relevant bundle gets inlined into the page. But the nearest approach I can find in next.js is to declare a `<Script>` tag in the index or _document file, either containing stringified JS or pointing to an external file:

```js
  <Script id="foo">{` console.log('hello') `}</Script>
or:
  <Script src="foo.js" strategy='beforeInteractive' ... />
```

These both work, but they require you to either maintain stringified JS, or to manually edit/bundle the external file.

Is there any better way to do this, to get Next.js to compile/minify/etc a module and then inline the results?